# Generate strings from type properties to be used as computed properties

Tags: typescript

Say I have a list of "nades" where a nade has this interface:

```
interface Nade {
  id: string;
  createdAt: Date | string;
  viewCount: number;
  favoriteCount: number;
  commentCount: number;
}
```

and I want to sort nades based on one of the possible sorting properties which could be denoted by:

```
type SortBy = Pick<Nade, "viewCount" | "favoriteCount" | "commentCount">;
```

So I have/want this function:

```
function sortNades(nades: Nade[], sortBy: SortBy = "viewCount") {
  return [...nades].sort((a, b) => b[sortBy] - a[sortBy]);
}
```

where `sortBy: SortBy = "viewCount"` is the conceptual part that I'm trying to achieve. `sortBy` should only be able to be one of the possible `SortBy` types and is defaulted to viewCount.

I am aware you can't use types and computed properties interchangeable exactly like this, but I'm wondering then if possible, how can I generate the strings from the types automatically?

Something like this for example, but I **don't** want to have to implement it manually:

```
const SortByStrings = {
  viewCount: "viewCount",
  favoriteCount: "favoriteCount",
  commentCount: "commentCount",
}
```

But rather I want to compute `SortByStrings` from `SortBy` automatically, if possible. Even better would be if I didn't have to use/compute `SortByStrings` at all.

Comment: So that we can understand better, how do you intend to use sortByStrings ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqQQQm) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; otherwise please explain what use cases are unsatisfied by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyof` ([documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)) operator to define your `SortBy` type as following :

```
interface Nade {
  id: string;
  createdAt: Date | string;
  viewCount: number;
  favoriteCount: number;
  commentCount: number;
}

type SortBy = keyof Pick<Nade, "viewCount" | "favoriteCount" | "commentCount">;
```

Now, all `SortType` variables have to equals either "viewCount", "favoriteCount" or "commentCount". You can then use it like that :

```
function sortNades(nades: Nade[], sortBy: SortBy = "viewCount") {
  return [...nades].sort((a, b) => b[sortBy] - a[sortBy]);
}

const nades = [
    {
        id: '1',
        createdAt: 'before',
        viewCount: 5,
        favoriteCount: 65,
        commentCount: 20
    },
        {
        id: '2',
        createdAt: 'after',
        viewCount: 10,
        favoriteCount: 10,
        commentCount: 10
    }
]

const result = sortNades(nades, 'viewCount')
```

**Make it generic**

You can make it generic if you want to reuse this concept for other interfaces/types, as following :

```
type SortBy<T, V extends keyof T> = V

type NadeSortableKeys = SortBy<Nade, 'viewCount' | 'favoriteCount' | 'commentCount'>

function sortNades(nades: Nade[], NadeSortableKeys: SortByNade = "viewCount") {
    return [...nades].sort((a, b) => b[sortBy] - a[sortBy]);
}

sortNades([], 'viewCount') // no type error
sortNades([], 'createdAt') // triggers error
```

Comment: Is `type SortBy<T, V extends keyof T> = keyof Pick<T, V>` any different from just `type SortBy<T, V extends keyof T> = V`?

Comment: Seems to be the same indeed, thanks for noticing :)